# Div display based on radio selection

Tags: javascript, jquery

Currently I have a piece of code that works fine as long as there are no other divs in the page.  If I add other divs, they will close upon any radio selection.  I just need a simple modification to the code to open and close without closing all other divs.  The working example can be seen here.

http://jsfiddle.net/L5qfn/38/

I added the "wrapper" to the entire contents of the body to demonstrate how everything closes.  Take out the wrapper...and things work like I want it to.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem comes from your `<div id="wrapper">`, and this line :

```
 $('div[class!="formset"]').slideUp("fast"); //Slide Up Effect
```

I rather suggest to change it to :

```
    $('div .sub-formset').slideUp("fast"); //Slide Up Effect
```

See the result : http://jsfiddle.net/L5qfn/40/

Answer (score 1):

The problem is caused by the following line:

```
$('div[class!="formset"]').slideUp("fast");
```

That basically says "hide any `div` which does not have the class `formset`". The wrapper `div` does not have that class, so it gets hidden. I'm not sure what that line is doing (it appears to do nothing useful in the fiddle at least) so I'd suggest just removing it, unless you can expand upon your problem.

Here's an [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/interdream/L5qfn/39/).

**Update** based on comments

As @fflorent has mentioned, it looks like you actually wanted to hide `.sub-formset`, so you probably want to change that selector to:

```
$(".sub-formset").slideUp("fast");
```

Note that I've used a class selector (the `.` character) rather than using an attribute equals selector as you've done in your fiddle.

Comment: yes, i agree, i was just going to post this same answer, nice job james!! up+1 from me :)

Comment: I think he/she wanted to hide the sub-forms, since if you select *Yes*, then *No*, and finally *Maybe*, you get the sub-forms 3 times

Comment: @fflorent - Ahh, yes, I think you're right. +1 on your answer.

Comment: This works but it does not hide the other div's when you change the radio selection.

Comment: The code was intended to hide the div associated with the selection...but it ended up hiding ALL divs.  The code left by fflorent below fixed the problem!

Comment: @JamesWilliams - Yeah, see above comments and update to answer.